# How to stop Seaborn residplot ignoring hue (colour) when scatter_kws is used in PairGrid

Tags: python, python-3.x, seaborn

First generate some random data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import random

categories = pd.DataFrame(np.array(["p","q"])[np.random.randint(0,2,size=[100,1])],columns=["cat"],dtype="object")
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(100,2),columns=list('AB'))
df = pd.concat([data,categories],axis=1)

df.head()
          A         B cat
0  0.384899  0.780235   q
1  0.882805  0.191988   q
2  0.088372  0.411098   p
3  0.894406  0.991639   p
4  0.756944  0.250110   q
```

I create a pairplot as follows:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df,hue="cat")
g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g.map_lower(sns.residplot)
g.map_upper(sns.regplot)
```

Which looks like this:

[image]

This is OK. But I want to change the size of the points. So I try to do this using the `scatter_kws` argument:

```
g = sns.PairGrid(df,hue="cat")
g.map_diag(plt.hist)
g.map_lower(sns.residplot,scatter_kws={'s':10})
g.map_upper(sns.regplot,scatter_kws={'s':10})
```

But now the two classes are no longer colour-separated in the residplot!

[image]

How do I get the two classes to be coloured, whilst also being able to change the size?

(python 3.6.4, seaborn 0.8.1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a bug or some other strange behaviour in the mapping, since the subsequent calls to the mapped function receive different arguments.

A solution is to manually perform the mapping taking care of the correct arguments being passed.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

N = 100
categories = pd.DataFrame(np.array(["p","q"])[np.random.randint(0,2,size=[N,1])],
                          columns=["cat"],dtype="object")
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(N,2),columns=list('AB'))
df = pd.concat([data,categories],axis=1)

g = sns.PairGrid(df,hue="cat")
g.map_diag(plt.hist)

g.map_upper(sns.regplot,scatter_kws={'s':10})

def f(*args, **kwargs): 
    if 'scatter_kws' in kwargs.keys():
        kwargs['scatter_kws'].update({"color": kwargs.pop("color")})
    sns.residplot(*args,**kwargs)
g.map_lower(f, scatter_kws={'s':10})
```

[image]